Resize a div with absolute position
Is it possible to resize a div with absolute position?
I want this pink modal to keep the same width of the input & resize with it.
This modal will be used in a dropdown component. So, should be resized as a whole with input.
By the way, is absolute position a correct choice for such a use case?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My CSS Grid</title>
    <style>
      body {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: "Nunito Semibold";
        text-align: center;
      }
      .page {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
        grid-gap: 10px;
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        grid-template-areas:
          "header header header"
          "aside comp main";
      }
      .page > * {
        background: #3bbced;
        padding: 10px;
      }

      .header {
        grid-area: header;
      }
      .comp {
        grid-area: comp;
      }
      .input_cell {
        display: grid;
      }
      .input {
        flex: 1;
      }
      .modal_container {
        margin-top: 20px;
        flex: 1;

        background-color: pink;
        position: absolute;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="header">Header</div>
      <div class="comp">
        <div class="input_cell">
          <input class="input" />
          <div class="modal_container">Modal</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>






<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My CSS Grid</title>
    <style>
      body {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: "Nunito Semibold";
        text-align: center;
      }
      .page {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
        grid-gap: 10px;
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        grid-template-areas:
          "header header header"
          "aside comp main";
      }
      .page > * {
        background: #3bbced;
        padding: 10px;
      }

      .header {
        grid-area: header;
      }
      .comp {
        grid-area: comp;
        position: relative;
      }
      .input_cell {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
      }
      .input {
        flex: 1;
      }
      .modal_container {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: pink;
        margin-top: 20px;
        flex: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="header">Header</div>
      <div class="comp">
        <div class="input_cell">
          <input class="input" />
          <div class="modal_container">Modal</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



Set .comp,.input_cell position relative. Styling .modal_container width 100%
